# Виртуальные функции

Tags: c++, virtual

описал класс вот так

```
#pragma once
#include "Port.h"

class Factory {
public:
    virtual ~Factory() {}
    virtual Port* create_ship() = 0;
};
```

При этом выдается ошибка: 
Ошибка  C2143   синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "*" KR  C:\Users\Nikita\source\repos\KR\KR\Factory.h    7
Ошибка  C2433   Factory::Port: "virtual" не разрешается для объявлений данных   KR  C:\Users\Nikita\source\repos\KR\KR\Factory.h    7
Ошибка  C4430   отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию    KR  C:\Users\Nikita\source\repos\KR\KR\Factory.h    7

Класс Port 
Путь к файлу Port.h - C:\Users\Nikita\source\repos\KR\KR

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Factory.h"

using namespace std;

class Port {
    vector<Port*> ships;

protected:
    string type;            //Тип
    string ship_class;      //Класс корабля
    string special_term;    //Специальное назначение
    string sailing_area;    //Район плавания
    string power_plant;     //Энергетическая установка


    int dimensions[3];      //Габариты (длина, ширина, высота)
    int displacement;       //Водоизмещение
    int capacity;           //Вместимость
    int team;               //Экипаж
    int passengers;         //Пассажиры
    int speed[2];           //Скорость

public:
    //Функции ввода данных
    void enter_ship_class();
    void enter_special_term();
    void enter_sailing_area();
    void enter_power_plant();
    void enter_dimensions();
    void enter_displacement();
    void enter_capacity();
    void enter_team();
    void enter_passengers();
    void enter_speed();

    //Добваление кораблей
    void add_ship(Factory& factory);

    //Удаление кораблей
    void delete_ship();

    //Функция вывода данных о кораблях
    void display_ships_data();

    //Редактирование данных
    void change_ships_data();

    //Запись в файл
    void write_file();
};
```

В чем прикол?

Comment: В настройках нужно подправить путь к хедерам. Или с названием файла ошиблись. Или класс с другим именем. Или в другом пространстве имён.

Comment: вы случаем не сишным компилтором пытаетесь скомпилить?

Comment: Да нет, компилятор cpp, до написания этого класса все было нормально

Comment: Чтобы быстрее всё исправить покажите класс `Port` и имя файла где он находится.

Comment: Циклические инклюды...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас инклуды циклически заходят друг в друга. В вашем случае надо сделать предварительное объявление класса.

```
#pragma once
//#include "Port.h"

class Port ;

class Factory {
public:
    virtual ~Factory() {}
    virtual Port* create_ship() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Пока-что `#include"Port.h"` - уберите.